# How to generate a Receipt Page after Stripe Checkout

Tags: reactjs, api, material-ui, stripe-payments

I am new to stripe and APIs and followed a tutorial to implement stripe checkout and implemented that successfully but I want to display a receipt after stripe checkout.

Do you know any such tutorial or can anyone please help.

Also, after the payment, in the stripe dashboard I am getting status as incomplete and it says that three_d_secure authentication is required which I had turned on in the setting but whenever I enter card details it never asks. Would like to learn that too. Let me know if there are any good resources for the same. Would be grateful to have someone guideme.

`Code for listening on port 4000`

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
require("dotenv").config()
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_TEST)
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(cors())

app.post("/payment", cors(), async (req, res) => {


    let { amount, id } = req.body
    try {
        const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount,
            currency: "USD",
            description: "pay",
            payment_method: id,
            confirm: true
        })
        
        console.log("Payment", payment)

        res.json({
            message: "Payment successful",
            success: true
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
        res.json({
            message: "Payment failed",
            success: false
        })
    }
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, () => {
    console.log("Sever is listening on port 4000")
})
```

`code for checkout form`

```
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import { CardNumberElement, CardExpiryElement, CardCvcElement } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import {ArrowForward } from '@material-ui/icons';
import axios from "axios"
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './styles.css';
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Alert } from "@material-ui/core";
import { LoadingButton } from "@material-ui/lab";
import {Button, TextField, Paper, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import StripeInput from "../../src/components/StripeInput";


const CARD_OPTIONS = {
    iconStyle: "solid",
    style: {
        base: {
            iconColor: "#c4f0ff",
            color: "#fff",
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontFamily: "Roboto, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif",
            fontSize: "16px",
            fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
            ":-webkit-autofill": { color: "#fce883" },
            "::placeholder": { color: "#87bbfd" }
        },
        invalid: {
            iconColor: "#ffc7ee",
            color: "#ffc7ee"
        }
    }
}

export default function PaymentForm() {
    const [success, setSuccess ] = useState(false)
    const stripe = useStripe()
    const elements = useElements()
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        setLoading(true);
        e.preventDefault()
        const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement)
        })


    if(!error) {
        try {
            const {id} = paymentMethod
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/payment", {
                amount: 1000,
                id
            })

            if(response.data.success) {
                console.log("Successful payment")
                setSuccess(true)
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error", error)
        }
    } else {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

const paperStyle={padding:'30px 20px', width: 600, margin: "20px auto"}
const marginTop = { marginTop: 10} 
    return (
        <center>
        <>
        {!success ? 
        <div>
          <Grid>
          <Paper  elevation ={20} style = {paperStyle} >
          <Grid align='center'></Grid>


        <form>
       
        <Grid  item xs ={12}></Grid>
           <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField 
            //placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX"
            label="Card Number"
            style={marginTop}
            fullWidth
            InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            InputProps={{
                inputComponent: StripeInput,
                inputProps: {
                     component: CardNumberElement
                },
           }}
            />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField 
            //placeholder="MM/YY"
            fullWidth
            label="Expiry Date"
            style={marginTop}
            InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            InputProps={{
                inputComponent: StripeInput,
                inputProps: {
                    component: CardExpiryElement
                },
            }}
            />
            </Grid>
            <Grid  item xs ={12}></Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField 
            //placeholder="XXX"
            fullWidth
            label="CVV"
            style={marginTop}
            InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            InputProps={{
                inputComponent: StripeInput,
                inputProps: {
                    component: CardCvcElement
                },
            }}
            />
            </Grid>
            
            <Grid  item xs ={12}></Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <LoadingButton 
            loading ={loading}
            loadingPosition="start"
            startIcon={<ArrowForward />}
            fullWidth 
            variant="outlined"  
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            style={marginTop}>
                Pay
            </LoadingButton>
            </Grid>
        </form>
        </Paper>
       </Grid>
       <center>
       
    </center>
       </div>
        :
        <Grid>
          <Paper  elevation ={20} style = {paperStyle} >
          <Grid align='center'></Grid>
       <Alert severity="success">
           Your payment is Successful. Thanks for using our service.
       </Alert> 
       </Paper>
       </Grid>
      
        }




        </>
        </center>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about sending receipts from Stripe on successful payment or refunds [here](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts)

To your second question, use card no 4000 0025 0000 3155  to test 3D secure integration. Read more [here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards)

Comment: Thank you @RobLjm, I tried the card no given above but 3ds doesn't pop-up. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: From what I can understand, 3D Secure auth is done only when the card or the bank requires it. Have you tried testing with card no 4242 4242 4242 4242(it is  a valid card which doesn't require 3ds )?

Comment: @SarahKaiser it might help if you shared exactly the code you're using or the exact tutorial you're following.

Comment: @RobLjm I tried 4242 4242 4242 4242 also but in dashboard it still says incomplete, 3ds authentication required

Comment: @karllekko, hey, actually I lost the URL to the original tutorial but it was very similar to this one here --> https://betterprogramming.pub/stripe-api-tutorial-with-react-and-node-js-1c8f2020a825

Comment: @SarahKaiser Do post your code. We can't help you further without seeing the code.

Comment: @SarahKaiser Where in the settings did you turn on 3D secure? the blog you linked doesn't mention it anywhere

Comment: Hey, @RobLjm I have added the code here. Let me know if that helps you to help me.

Comment: @RobLjm, are there any updates for me?

Comment: 1._" it says that three_d_secure authentication is required which I had turned on in the setting"_.  Where and how have you turned on 3D secure?  2. And_"I want to display a receipt after stripe checkout._" What info do you want to display? Or do u just want the information that the Payment Intent has succeeded or failed?